# Canvas: Resizing image without blurring

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to represent an image in a canvas, and wish for the canvas to be a certain percent of its parent container's width. The trouble is I'm somehow blurring the image when adding it to the canvas, and I don't want to blur the image.

I thought adding `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false` would disable the blurring, but it doesn't appear to be helping.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the image below from blurring in this canvas? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/019f2ccb98391adbf460a10463059683/raw/c4c2bc1fa923d905aba0ef88e05c0760823d2cca/000630070000650.jpg';

img.onload = function() { 
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = hidden.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = hidden.clientHeight;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.drawImage(hidden,
    0, 0, this.naturalWidth, this.naturalHeight,
    0, 0, hidden.clientWidth, hidden.clientHeight)

}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  background: #efefef;
}

#hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000%;
}

#hidden,
#canvas {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/019f2ccb98391adbf460a10463059683/raw/c4c2bc1fa923d905aba0ef88e05c0760823d2cca/000630070000650.jpg' id='hidden'>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: if the canvas resolution does not match the display device resolution, Such as the canvas pixels are larger than display pixels then you will get artifacts. `imageSmoothingEnabled` (Smoothing is  bilinear filtering) only applies to the canvas content. The canvas is then rendered independent of its rendering context, to the page. You can use the CSS rule `image-rendering: pixelated` to prevent the browser from display the canvas using bilinear filtering.

Comment: @Blindman67 I confess I'm not sure what to make of your comment. I do know that the image (#hidden) and the canvas have the same size, and the latter is much grainier than the former (see Hugo's post below). Is it possible to achieve the level of detail in the image within the canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Canvas resolution and display size are not the same.

Looking at the image I see it is 444px by 800px in size which is very low resolution. How it displays will very much depend on the display device.

You have in your question, set the canvas display width to 60% of the containers size and the canvas resolution you have set to the image (444by800).

It is very likely that the display width and the canvas resolution do not match.

### Canvas display size

- `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height` represent the area on the page the image will fill and have nothing to do with the canvas resolution.

### Canvas resolution

- `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` properties represent the resolution of the canvas in pixels, the actual number of pixels used to store the image content

### Browser is adding the blur.

Assuming the 60% (for `#hidden {width : 60%}`) is of a HD display 1920px wide the canvas will be stretched over `60% * 1920 = 1152px` which is 2.6 times larger than the canvas.

The canvas content is not blurred, you have drawn the image correctly. It is the browser that is rendering the canvas onto the page at a size larger than the the canvas resolution that is adding the blurring.

### Simple fix

To stop the browser from blurring the content of the canvas use the CSS attribute `image-rendering: pixelated;` as in the example below.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/019f2ccb98391adbf460a10463059683/raw/c4c2bc1fa923d905aba0ef88e05c0760823d2cca/000630070000650.jpg';

img.onload = function() { 
  canvas.width = this.naturalWidth
  canvas.height = this.naturalHeight
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;  // not needed as you are not streaching the image
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

}
```

```css
.big {
  width:100%;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="big" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

### Simple sharpen two tone B/W.

The image is very low resolution so there is not much you can do to improve the quality in most cases.

But as it is a two tone Black & White  (not black, grays, and white) you can stretch it out on a larger canvas and increase the contrast to remove some of the blurring introduced when rendered to the canvas.

It is done by using the screen and color-burn composite operations to render the canvas on top of itself several times. Contrast is increase to reduce the blur yet keeping a less pixelated look.

To highlight the difference Only the left half of the image has been sharpened using this method.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/019f2ccb98391adbf460a10463059683/raw/c4c2bc1fa923d905aba0ef88e05c0760823d2cca/000630070000650.jpg';

img.onload = function() { 
  const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); //Get the canvas display sise
  
  canvas.width = bounds.width;
  canvas.height = this.naturalHeight * (bounds.width / this.naturalWidth);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // draw to canvas 
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // draw again using screen to up white areas
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height,0, 0,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height);
  // draw again to pukl grays down some 
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color-burn";
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height,0, 0,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height);
  // draw again using screen to up white areas
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height,0, 0,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height);
  // draw again to pukl grays down some 
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color-burn";
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height,0, 0,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height);
  
}
```

```css
.big {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="big" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks for this very helpful overview. I have just one quick clarifying question: Is it possible for the canvas resolution to be, say 1000px by 1000px, while the canvas display size is only 10px by 10px? If so, what does a canvas pixel represent in this case? I thought pixels had some kind of direct mapping to underlying hardware, but I know very little on this subject...

Comment: If you have a hi res canvas with a small display size the hardware will display an approx average of all the pixels contained in the display pixel. A lot of information will be ignored. Modern display hardware renders all pixels via the GPU. In effect your display is using the same code as a 3D game uses just without the depth coordinates. 
@duhaime Each image, panel, etc is rendered to texture buffers, which in turn are combined into larger buffers,  Only at the very end of each display cycle (~60Fps) does the final render move pixels to a buffer with a 1 to 1 match with display pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you need, but I was surprised by the top: -1000%. If, for example, in this case, the container gives "position: relative" the properties of the children with% will be relative to the parent.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/019f2ccb98391adbf460a10463059683/raw/c4c2bc1fa923d905aba0ef88e05c0760823d2cca/000630070000650.jpg';

img.onload = function() { 
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = hidden.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = hidden.clientHeight;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.drawImage(hidden,
    0, 0, this.naturalWidth, this.naturalHeight,
    0, 0, hidden.clientWidth, hidden.clientHeight)

}
```

```css
 

#container {
  width: 800px;
  background: #efefef;
  position:relative;
}

#hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#hidden, canvas {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/duhaime/019f2ccb98391adbf460a10463059683/raw/c4c2bc1fa923d905aba0ef88e05c0760823d2cca/000630070000650.jpg' id='hidden'>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: the purpose of the `top: -1000%` is to hide the image itself. As you can see, the image itself is not as fuzzy as the canvas (in your gist, the canvas is on the left, the img on the right). My goal is to hide the img and keep the canvas crisp looking.