# Scaling canvas shapes with 100% width canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to create an example of a canvas element with 100% width, containing a red square "border" rect. If I set the width of a canvas element in CSS to be 100%, it will successfully grow to fit the full width of the viewport, but the rect is blurred because CSS just stretches the canvas. This is demonstrated here:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I can set the canvas height and width to be equal to `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` as demonstrated below, which means the canvas will not bet stretched, but now my canvas context dimensions are no longer 300 x 150, and I won't know what the actual dimensions are in advance. How can do my canvas drawing with predictable dimensions liek 300 x 150, but also scale the canvas element to be 100% width? Webgl has `gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);` which I believe solves this problem, does canvas have a similar approach, or do you need to scale all the of dimensions of your shapes to have the same scaling that is applied to the canvas element? e.g. multiply by `clientWidth / 300` and `clientHeight / 150`?

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: This answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49972035/3877726

Answer (score 0):

A good solution seems to be using the `.scale()` method on the canvas context as per below. This way you can work with whatever coordinate system you like in the canvas context.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.scale(canvas.clientWidth / 300, canvas.clientHeight / 150);
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```